# Primal of the edge cover problem

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Given an undirected graph $G=\left(V,E\right)$. In the primal problem, we want to find a subset $E'\subseteq E$ of edges, whose size $|E'|$ as small as possible, under the following requirement: every vertex in $V$ must touch at least one edge of $E'$. Formulate the primal problem.

In the solution they wrote:

> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \min&\sum_{e\in G}x_{e}=|E'|\\&\forall u,v\in V,\,\sum_{e=\{u,v\}\in E}x_{e}\geq\frac{1}{2}\\&x_{e}\geq0
> \end{align*}
> $$

I don't understand where the $\frac{1}{2}$ came from. Is it possible to explain how do actually get to this linear program? I always encounter those question, and not sure how to formulate the program. Which steps you make to get to this program?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer all of your questions so let's start with the more general one.

The first step is to pick your variables ($x_e$ in this case). If you think what "find a subset" means you'll see that we have a lot of edges and for each one we must select whether to keep or discard it. Therefore, let represent said choice with $x_e$. That is $x_e = 1$ if edge $e$ is kept; otherwise $x_e = 0$.

Once we have our variables, we must define the objective: a set as small as possible. The cardinality of the set is precisely $\sum\limits_{e\in G} x_e$. (I am letting you check this) Since we asked for the smaller set = minimization, our objective becomes $\min\sum\limits_{e\in G} x_e$

And finally, the tricky part: the restrictions. Now, "a set of edges is a valid cover if for every vertex there is at least one adjacent edge". Translating the last sentence into notation:
$$ \forall v \in G: \exists u \in \mathcal{N}(v):\ x_{(v,u)} = 1$$
Or, by using summation,
$$ \forall v \in G:\ \sum\limits_{u \in \mathcal{N}(v)}x_{(v,u)} \ge 1$$

Now, our notation seems different from the one in your book. Let's examine closer. Note, if $u \not\in \mathcal{N}(v)$  there wasn't an edge $(u,v)$ in $E$. Which mean we can write

$$ \forall v \in G:\ \sum\limits_{u \in G: e = (u,v)\in E} x_e \ge 1$$

And we are almost there. At first sight, this looks the same as:
$$ \forall v,u \in G:\ \sum\limits_{e=(u,v)\in E} = x_e \ge 1$$

However, with the last change we count each edge exactly twice. For instance,  we count the edge $(x,y)$ once for $v=x, u=y$ and once for $v=y, u=x$. The $\frac{1}{2}$ offsets this change.